# Monthly max and min values along with corresponding date in df

Tags: pandas, group-by

Yearly data of stocks in following format

```
   Unnamed: 0       SC_NAME SC_GROUP     HIGH      LOW    CLOSE  NO_OF_SHRS     ISIN_CODE TRADING_DATE  Month  Year Mt_Year Qtr_Year
0           0      ABB LTD.        A  2280.90  2224.20  2234.85        7219  INE117A01022   2021-12-31     12  2021   12-21   2021-4
1           1   AEGIS LOGIS        A   223.90   217.65   221.80       49973  INE208C01025   2021-12-31     12  2021   12-21   2021-4
2           2  AMAR RAJA BA        A   638.35   621.05   636.85      149244  INE885A01032   2021-12-31     12  2021   12-21   2021-4
3           3    A.SARABHAI        X    34.40    31.50    33.65      367979  INE432A01017   2021-12-31     12  2021   12-21   2021-4
4           4          HDFC        A  2608.00  2555.60  2586.85       48669  INE001A01036   2021-12-31     12  2021   12-21   2021-4
```

Expecting following:

Month wise or quarterly high and Low along with corresponding dates for all SC_NAME

result = data.groupby(['Year','Mt_Year','SC_NAME']).agg({'HIGH':['max'],'LOW':['min']})

along with corresponding date for HIGH and LOW Values.

```
                          HIGH       LOW     Date for high   Date for low        ISIN_CODE SC_GROUP
                            max       min
```

Year Mt_Year SC_NAME
2021 01-21    EMERALD         17.35     11.40                                      INE030Q01015       X
20 MICRONS       42.20     36.15                                       INE144J01027       B
21ST CEN.MGM     11.50     10.30                                      INE253B01015       B

...                             ...       ...           ...      ...
12-21   ZODIAC VEN       32.40     22.10                                     INE945J01027       X
ZOMATO          157.80    124.70                                      INE758T01015       B
ZUARI AGRO      125.40    101.50                                      INE840M01016       B

Thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use `idxmax` and `idxmin` to get the lowest and the max index then extract `TRADING_DATE` for both:

```
out = (df.groupby(['Year', 'Month', 'SC_NAME'], as_index=False)
         .agg(PRICE_HIGH=('HIGH', 'max'),
              DATE_HIGH=('HIGH', 'idxmax'),
              PRICE_LOW=('LOW', 'min'),
              DATE_LOW=('LOW', 'idxmin'),
              ISIN_CODE=('ISIN_CODE', 'first')))

out['DATE_HIGH'] = df.loc[out['DATE_HIGH'].tolist(), 'TRADING_DATE']
out['DATE_LOW'] = df.loc[out['DATE_LOW'].tolist(), 'TRADING_DATE']
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   Year  Month       SC_NAME  PRICE_HIGH   DATE_HIGH  PRICE_LOW    DATE_LOW     ISIN_CODE
0  2021     12    A.SARABHAI       34.40  2021-12-31      31.50  2021-12-31  INE432A01017
1  2021     12      ABB LTD.     2280.90  2021-12-31    2224.20  2021-12-31  INE117A01022
2  2021     12   AEGIS LOGIS      223.90  2021-12-31     217.65  2021-12-31  INE208C01025
3  2021     12  AMAR RAJA BA      638.35  2021-12-31     621.05  2021-12-31  INE885A01032
4  2021     12          HDFC     2608.00  2021-12-31    2555.60  2021-12-31  INE001A01036
```

Comment: Corralien, Thanks for reply. But it is not working. I am not getting dates in Date_High and Date_Low. Will you please check again

Comment: Can you update your post with clean data and reproducible example, please?